# fread() puts weird things into char array

Tags: c, xcode, file-io

I have a file that I want to be read from and printed out to the screen. I'm using XCode as my IDE. Here is my code...

```
fp=fopen(x, "r");
char content[102];
fread(content, 1, 100, fp);
printf("%s\n", content);
```

The content of the file is "Bacon!" What it prints out is `\254\226\325k\254\226\234`.

I have Googled all over for this answer, but the documentation for file I/O in C seems to be sparse, and what little there is is not very clear. (To me at least...)

EDIT: I switched to just reading, not appending and reading, and switched the two middle arguments in `fread()`. Now it prints out `Bacon!\320H\320` What do these things mean? Things as in backslash number number number or letter. I also switched the way to print it out as suggested.

Comment: Don't ever use a format string read from anywhere !. In this case, either use `puts()` or `printf("%s", content)`

Comment: @Dani the question tells you that it's "Bacon!" Were you doubting the power of bacon?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you have switched the `size` and `nmemb` arguments. :)

Comment: You should also clear the content of your buffer with `memset()`, and ultimately, check the return value of `fread()` to know the number of element read and add a `'\0'` on the last buffer position to terminate the string before trying to print it.

Comment: I strongly recommend you check for errors and number of bytes read when you call `read` family functions.

Comment: @ydroneaud: Clearing is not necessary if you check number of bytes read. Filling array with 0 doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are opening the file for *appending and reading*. You should be opening it for *reading*, or moving your read pointer to the place from which you are going to read (the beginning, I assume).

```
FILE *fp = fopen(x, "r");
```

or

```
FILE *fp = fopen(x, "a+");
rewind(fp);
```

Also, `fread(...)` does not zero-terminate your string, so you should terminate it before printing:

```
size_t len = fread(content, 1, 100, fp);
content[len] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", content);
```

Comment: a+ opens it for reading and appending (according to my local man page), which should read file from the start... (I've learned something today!)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good point, I updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! What finally fixed it was the `content[len]='\0';`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you meant this:

```
printf("%s\n", content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
fp = fopen(x, "a+");
if(fp)
{
    char content[102];
    memset(content, 0 , 102);

    // arguments are swapped.
    // See : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/
    // You want to read 1 byte, 100 times
    fread(content, 1, 100, fp);

    printf("%s\n", content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that you do not terminate the data you read, so `printf` prints the buffer until it finds a string terminator.